# All business logic in stored procedure

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, logic

My project's using N-Tier architecture and common framework as:

- Presentation Layer: JSF 2.0 + Primefaces
- Business Logic Layer: Spring for management transaction
- Data access Layer: Spring Data + JPA
- Spring security for security and user management
- Spring integration for integration with external system

For almost all business logic, we're using Java code and reside in Business Layer, but my client requires that we move all business logic into the database and use stored procedures (database is Oracle).

I tried to convince my client and give some disadvantage and advantage if move business logic to database as below:

**Disadvantages**:

- Stored procedure is not programming language, it should use for manage data and not for write logic code
- Stored procedure make logic become complex. One logic maybe difficult to implement with stored procedure but very easy if use programming language as Java
- Difficult to debug or unit test
- Diffucult to handler exception
- Difficult for maintenance, update
- Stored procedure can't integrate with external system
- Take much effort to write CRUD for each table when ORM Framework's really good for CRUD
- Difficult to make clear design document
- More bugs
- Slow down development process
- Database server will become overloaded
- Database should use for handling data not for process logic
- Difficult and expensive to upgrade or add new database server, but easier and cheaper with application server
- Break N-Tier architecture and ORM framework

When using stored procedures:

- **Performance**: Process batch data or long time process with database (as report...)

My client also said: they want use store to fix project without redeploy. And I explain that when change business logic maybe we need change input, output and user interface, then we still have to redeploy, and we should bring business logic out of database. But they rejected.

Comment: I don't think  user interface need to be change if you are going for stored procedure.

Comment: some time, change logic need change UI.

Comment: This question is flawed since it does not separate write-oriented business logic from read-oriented business logic. The more I read arguments for and against logic in stored procedures, and the more I read about things like CQRS and immutability, the more I see that optimizing writes and reads require different classes of business logic. What are you asking about, both categories of write and read logic or only one? You seem to be getting at the idea I agree with, which  is put data-heavy, set-based operations in stored procedures such as for reporting or large scale operations.

Answer (score -1):

If you using ORACLE DB then never try to underestimate the power of Stored Procedure.I worked in many very heavy application and yes which had JAVA layer but processing huge data with business logic was not possible at all in JAVA layer. So we moved most of the data processing logic in stored procedure and it rocks like anything.

For an example you want to show a logical report at front end and you are sure it will be only few Kbs and you know to generate this report you calling DB and fetching records in MB and doing business logic in JAVA, will it be fast??

I am java guy but still supports stored procedure as you can do a lot even you can write useful business logic in it.

As well stored procedure works in DB layer so its always fast compare to JAVA.as per my opinion the complex DB related queries which you have in JAVA business layer just move to stored procedure and retrieve the required output by using java and display the same at frontend.

In Addition I want to put best Pros of stored procedure.

- Its Faster because multiple SQL queries and such can be performed in one "round trip" to the database
- Trivial to make use of the stored procedures from multiple applications
- One place is easier to maintain than multiple
- Databases are fast and optimized and can be scaled well.
- The same procedures can be called from mutiple, different frameworks and languages.
- The logic is decoupled from the implementation in particular applications.
- Rework may be reduced for changing applications when the database stays the same.

Comment: I gree with you, when work with huge data and some function like reporting we will use store. But my client ask for ALL business logic, not some logic need performace.

Comment: It seems like this is the best argument for using stored procedures, for data-heavy, set-level operations, which are more often than not the read operations, not the write operations.